# Ключи и индексы в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с 5 полями.Нужно сделать составной первичный ключ из 4 полей, но так чтобы была возможность, чтобы некоторые из этих полей могли принимать значение null.
Подскажите как правильно сделать?

Comment: Можно обойтись без первичного ключа. Добавьте простой составной индекс и сделайте его уникальным

Comment: вы имеете в виду CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать уникальный индекс

```
create unique index priceline_key_idx
  on priceline (agent_guid, client_guid, flow, product_id);
```

Или индекс создается автоматически при указании ограничения.

```
alter table priceline add constraint priceline_key unique (agent_guid, client_guid, flow, product_id);
```

Учти

> При этом значения NULL считаются не равными друг другу. Составной
>   уникальный индекс не принимает только те строки, в которых все
>   индексируемые столбцы содержат одинаковые значения. [via](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/indexes-unique)

Тоесть можно вбить несколько одинаковых значений если одно из полей `NULL`.

Обойти это можно сделав столбец NOT NULL и указав `DEFAULT 0`, `DEFAULT ''` или эквивалент нужного типа.

Comment: примерно до этого дошел методом тыка)
спасибо! )

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно. `primary key` может быть [только строго `not null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS):

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index
>   on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key, and will
>   force the column(s) to be marked NOT NULL.

Добавление `primary key` создаст уникальный индекс по полям, а так же принудительно попробует проставить `NOT NULL` на все поля, указанные в первичном ключе.

Comment: а как тогда можно обеспечить уникальность таких полей?

Comment: сформулируйте исходную задачу. Что есть, что должно быть уникально, а что должно быть допустимо.

Comment: CREATE TYPE flow_types AS ENUM ( NULL,'direct','indirect' );   
CREATE TYPE seller_types AS ENUM ( NULL,'agent','private_trader' );   
CREATE TABLE priceline (   
    product_id                           BIGINT NOT NULL,
    price                                    INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    flow                                     flow_types,
    seller                                   seller_types,
    client_guid VARCHAR(48)  DEFAULT NULL,
    agent_guid VARCHAR(48) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (agent_guid, client_guid, flow, product_id)
);
пардоньте, форматирование не получается.

Comment: Через редактировать вопрос.